# Warning: control reaches end of non-void function; error: null undeclared (c)

Tags: c

```
q_node * pop(Queue * que) {
   if ((que->size == 0) || (que == NULL)) return null;
   q_node * item = que->head;
   if (freeNode(que)) {
      que->size--;
      return item;
   } else return null;
}
```

When I try to compile I get the above warning for the bottom line of this function. The structs q_node and Queue compiled with no problems, as did freeNode()...any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I also get the error "null undeclared" for the first if statement line.

Comment: You should ensure you return values from all *paths* inside the function. What if the function `freeNode()` returns false?

Comment: It's `NULL`, not `null`. C is case-sensitive.

Comment: ....did you just drastically edit your question? -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
q_node * pop(Queue * que) {
   if ((que->size == 0) || (que == NULL)) return NULL;
   q_node * item = que->head;
   if (freeNode(que)) {
      que->size--;
      return item;
   }
   return NULL;
}
```

remove the else statement is useless. No warnings now ^_^
Gcc see you miss a return statement at the end and is letting you know just in case.

EDIT: null -> NULL

Comment: His original function gave me no warnings after `#define null NULL`. `gcc`'s smart enough to realize that the `else` covers all cases.

Comment: indeed gcc rocks... did you try with `-Wall` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. `-Wall -Wextra -ansi -O`, still no warnings.

Comment: wow, no warnings ? oh well, ask user1436111 then :P he was the one who got the warnings in the first place, I can't compile that code to run some tests. ""Warning: control reaches end of non-void function""

Answer (score 1):

In C, use `NULL` instead of `null`. You may need to `#include <stdlib.h>` to get this macro.